# Intellij IDEA shortcut to "create field"?

Tags: intellij-idea

There is an useful functionality in IDEA that lets you create a field, and it appears in the little light-bulb when you highlight the non-created variable.

However, I can't find the short-cut, searched for "create field" in the settings but no luck.

Anyone knows?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Alt-Enter to access the lightbulb menu and then use the arrow keys to select the necessary option. There is no possibility to assign shortcuts to individual quickfixes (there are too many of them).

Answer (score 7):

Control + Alt + F on a literal will give you the option to extract the value into a field.

Comment: Yes, but it's not as practical as the light-bulb option.

Comment: Do you mean the light-bulb offers more functionality? What other functionality are you talking about? There are lots of extracting shortcuts (extract code into methods, literals into variables/constants, etc) but you will have to be more specific.

Comment: I didn't say more functionality, I said that it was more practical. For example, with just one click I generate the variable I was looking for, without having to type one character. If you use it you will understand.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, its ***option-command+F***.

Its much faster than Option-Enter, then you need some brain cycle to select create field in the down down menu